# Cannot read the changes in net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports

Tags: 14.04, proc, ipv4

I'm new to Ubuntu and I tried to edit this file  `net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports`
but cannot read changes. I got `empty` after I checked the file again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant file is `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_reserved_ports`, not `net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports`.

`net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports` is a kernel parameter whose value needs to be inserted using `sysctl`, you can edit the file directly but using `sysctl` is preferred.

You can do:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports='VALUE'
```

You can make it permanent by putting in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports=VALUE" >>/etc/sysctl.conf'
```

For example:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports=34566,34567" >>/etc/sysctl.conf'
```

Or

```
echo "net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports=VALUE" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Now load the `sysctl` settings (no need to restart):

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: should i restart netwwork or not ?

Comment: @Begnnier no need to restart anything..check my edits..just do `sudo sysctl -p`

Comment: @Begnnier I don't understand..its better to ask it as a new question with enough details..

Comment: the post here http://askubuntu.com/questions/710425/bind-failure-address-in-use-ephemeral-ports

Answer (score 0):

You have to do read/write as root. The file is `ip_local_reserved_ports` located in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4`.
So:

```
sudo echo "12345,12346,12347" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_reserved_ports
sudo cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_reserved_ports
12345-12347
```